# Expression of type KafkaProducer[String,String] doesn't conform to expected type Null

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I want to be able to initialize the variable `producer` from the function `setProducer`.

```
object MyObj { 
  var producer = null                                                                                                                  

  def setProducer(p: KafkaProducer[String,String]): Unit = {           
    producer = p                                                       
  }   

  //...
}
```

However it says that `Expression of type KafkaProducer[String,String] doesn't conform to expected type Null`.

So, how can I initialize `producer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a type for the variable, for example:

```
object MyObj { 
  var producer: KafkaProducer[String,String] = null                                                                                                                  

  def setProducer(p: KafkaProducer[String,String]): Unit = {           
    producer = p                                                       
  }   

  //...
}
```